# Interest only loan

Tags: loans

With an interest only loan that allows extra payments toward the principal, does the amount of interest due reduce or recalculate for subsequent payments as the outstanding principal is paid down by the extra payments?

Comment: What do the terms of the loan say? I would think that it would, but there are some evil loans out there.

Comment: Agree with @DStanley - you need to look at the terms of your loan, or ask your lender. Although, I've never heard of an interest-only loan that wouldn't adjust automatically if some of the loan principal was paid down. And I can't imagine the math that would be used to justify it *not* decreasing.

Comment: @dwizum Off the top of my head I can think of one justification, and that is if the term of the loan was decreased (or alternately, if the pre-payment was treated as if it was credited in the month it was actually due)

Comment: If it's a line of credit, then yes. If it's a defined term loan, then like the previous comments said, it depends on the rules of the loan. I'd say *probably* would reduce it, since otherwise it is no longer "interest only" if you overpay one time. :)

Comment: Probably, but it would be down to the terms of the lender as to when they considered the principal payments to actually apply to the principal, and where/when they charge any overpayment penalties

Comment: Hi Tim, welcome to Money.SE. The question, as written, with no additional details, cannot be answered. It depends on the type of loan, and what the agreement states. In general, the answer would be 'yes'. It sounds typical of a US HELOC (home equity line of credit), which is in its first phase, functioning similar to what you describe.